# get() method in Selenium making rouge HEAD Request

Tags: java, selenium

Upon using `get(URL)` method my automation is making rogue HTTP `HEAD` request before making HTTP `GET` request.

```java
String appURL = Property.getPropertyValue(configPptPath, "URL");
driver.get(appURL + "xml_generator/");
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes. Expected is my automation should make GET request, instead of HEAD request. Is there any way i can control these request method type in my automation?